# GcmListenerService client side notification

Tags: java, android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use gcm to push notifications on android devices. So far I have registered with gcm and sent my back-end the necessary information to make a post request to the gcm severs which builds a 200 response. All the steps have come together except the client side receiving the message. I don't get the message. Displayed here is my gcm listener class:

```
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    public static final int MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 435345;

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

        sendNotification(from,message);

    }

    private void sendNotification(String title, String body) {
        Context context = getBaseContext();
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<permission android:name="com.example.caesar.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.caesar.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <recieve android:name = ".GcmReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        <category android:name="com.example.caesar.gcm" />
    </intent-filter>

</recieve>


</application>
```

// new manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<permission android:name="com.example.caesar.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.caesar.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <reciever
        android:name = "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        <category android:name="com.example.caesar.gcm" />
    </intent-filter>

</reciever>
    <service
        android:name="com.example.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

Comment: Can you add your manifest.

Comment: ya sure could you also explain why the problem would be in the manifest

Comment: Well not familar with GCMListenerService, have previously and currently use a combination of classses to do what this seems to be doing.  But looking at https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client I figured that maybe you hadn't setup the Receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually looking at this further it looks like you haven't setup the receiver correctly.  Seems you need to include at least.

```
 <service
            android:name="com.example.MyGcmListenerService "
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

And for the rest just follow that link.

Comment: hi thanks for all the help. this is my new manifest file. if you dont have any other suggestions i can close this question

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your resgistration intent service at the end of yout Manifest file. Like this example:

```
    <service
            android:name="com.example.gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false">
    </service>
```

Hope that help you, more information, you can visit this [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) and you can view an example of RegistrationIntentService [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/RegistrationIntentService.java).